# CefSharp программно нажать на кнопку

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Доброго времени суток, не подскажите, как программно нажать на кнопку использую cefsharp (chromium), код кнопки

```
<button type="submit" class="button-download">Скачать 4.22 Mb<br/>по прямой ссылке</button>
```

Нужен пример именно с CefSharp, простой webbrowser тут не поможет, к сожалению. Можете помочь ?

код, который на данный момент я имею

```
public class DownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
        {
            public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

            public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

            public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
            {
                OnBeforeDownloadFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);

                if (!callback.IsDisposed)
                {
                    using (callback)
                    {
                        callback.Continue(@"C:\Users\ABS\Downloads\" +
                                downloadItem.SuggestedFileName,
                            showDialog: false);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
            {
                OnDownloadUpdatedFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);
            }
        }
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            // Create a browser component
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://link.ru");
            chromeBrowser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
```

Comment: Где вас пример кода?

Comment: В чем проблема написать код на JavaScript и выполнить его? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155779/cefsharp-execute-javascript

Comment: @Alex78191 я просто не знал этого, ибо в простом веббр будет примерн такой код
`document.getElementById('submit_bt').click()` Думал, что тут примерн тоже самое. Тобишь, надо сделать javascript код, который будет нажимать на кнопку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.button-download').click()
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="button-download" onclick="alert('Кнопка нажата.')">Скачать 4.22 Mb<br/>по прямой ссылке</button>
```

Вам нужно дождаться, когда браузер выполнит инициализацию, прежде чем выполнять большинство вещей, включая выполнение javascript. Вы можете подключить события `FrameLoadEnd` / `LoadingStateChanged` / `IRenderProcessMessageHandler.OnContextCreated` и сделать что-то вроде этого.

```
chromeBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;

private void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.button-download').click()");
    }
}
```

[Больше примеров в официальной справке](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можете подсказать, при вызове ExecuteScriptAsync выходит исключение `Unable to execute javascript at this time, scripts can only be executed within a V8Context.Use the IWebBrowser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame property to guard against this exception`

Comment: @Lolidze Выполните код не на локальной странице.

Comment: всм ? можете по подробнее

Comment: @Lolidze какой адрес у страницы?

Comment: `http://disk-space.ru/download/78a1f57bc2/bccrypto-csharp-1.8.1-bin.zip.html`

Comment: @Lolidze а если панель разработчика открыть, то будет исключение?

Comment: Если вы имели в виду вручную протестировать javascript код в браузере (F12 -> консоль -> `document.querySelector('.button-download').click()` ), то все норм, если же нет, то пожалуйста, перефразируйте и чуть более подробно, спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze нет, просто открыть панель разработчика и выполнить код через CefSharp.

Comment: простите за нубство, но я без понятия, как это сделать. Можете чуть подробнее расписать все это действие ?

Comment: @Lolidze посмотрите обновленный ответ